# How to send a message by guild ID and channel ID in Discord.NET

Tags: .net-core, discord, bots, discord.net

Good day, I am stuck with my discord bot. I am using the Discord.NET library and my task is to get a command in direct messages and send it into one specific channel in a specific discord guild. I know both channel and guild IDs but I am not sure how to use these.

```
[Command("resource")]
public async Task SendResource(string url = null, [Remainder]string description = null)
{
    if (url == null)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("...");
        return;
    }
    if (description == null)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("...");
        return;
    }
    string text = $"**New resource:** {url}\n**Description:** {description}";
    await Context.Guild.GetTextChannel(863427166662557696).SendMessageAsync(text);
}
```

```
await Context.Guild.GetTextChannel(863427166662557696).SendMessageAsync(text);
```

will find the channel at the same guild but it won't work if the command was executed in direct messages

I've done some researches and found GetGuild(id) method that gets the guild as an object but to call this method belongs to DiscordSocketClient which is declared in CommandHandler

How can I send the message to the certain discord guilt channel from command executed in direct messages? Thanks!

Comment: You have to get the guild first, so yes you need to call GetGuild. You should have access to the DiscordSocketClient via the Context

Comment: @Anu6is, so how to do it? How to access client via the context?

Comment: simply Context.Client

Answer (score 0):

Since I was following the discord.net guides template I simply added DiscordSocketClient client in my class constructor and it worked.

Comment: That is completely unnecessary. Like I stated in the comments above, command modules already have access to the client via `Context`. See the [docs](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.Commands.CommandContext.html#Discord_Commands_CommandContext_Client)

Comment: @Anu6is Context has no method GetGuild or GetTextChannel. My command must be able to be executed in both PM and server channel as I wrote in the question

Comment: I never said Context has a `GetGuild` or `GetTextChannel` method. I said context has access to the `DiscordSocketClient` from which you can call `GetGuild`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
[Command("resource")]
public async Task SendResource(string url = null, [Remainder]string description = null)
{
    if (url == null)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("...");
        return;
    }
    if (description == null)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("...");
        return;
    }
    string text = $"**New resource:** {url}\n**Description:** {description}";
    await Context.Client.GetGuild(123456789).GetTextChannel(863427166662557696).SendMessageAsync(text);
}
```

Note the change from
`Context.Guild.GetTextChannel(channel_id).SendMessageAsync(text);`
to
`Context.Client.GetGuild(guild_id).GetTextChannel(channel_id).SendMessageAsync(text);`